# sql database oracle constraints

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

why not NULL constraint is not applicable for more than one column?

Comment: be specific on what you are trying to create and what issue you faced in the process

Comment: you can apply a not null constraint for multiple columns. For an existing table use alter table tab1 modify col1 not null; alter table tab1 modify col2 not null;

Answer (score -1):

Not Null Constraint can applicable for more than one rows just like primary key apply in Oracle
answer

1. **create table emp (empno number, empfname varchar2(15), emplname varchar2(15), NOT NULL(empfname,emplname));**